# Pandas: get rows with exactly one 0

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Given the df:

```
foo bar baz
0   0   0
0   5   3
1   0   2
1   6   1
```

I want to get only the rows with exactly one 0:

```
foo bar baz
0   5   3
1   0   2
```

I know `df.loc[df['foo'] == 0]` will give me all rows where 0 is in the foo column, but it doesn't compare across the row to make sure there is only one 0. My actual data has many more columns, so I'd love a solution that doesn't involve typing out each column title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df.eq(0).sum(1).eq(1)` as the condition:

```
df[df.eq(0).sum(1).eq(1)]

#   foo  bar  baz
#1    0    5    3
#2    1    0    2
```

---

Whether elements are equal to `0`:

```
df.eq(0)
#     foo    bar    baz
#0   True   True   True
#1   True  False  False
#2  False   True  False
#3  False  False  False
```

Count zeros by row:

```
df.eq(0).sum(1)
#0    3
#1    1
#2    1
#3    0
#dtype: int64
```

Check whether each row has only one zero:

```
df.eq(0).sum(1).eq(1)
#0    False
#1     True
#2     True
#3    False
#dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
zero_cells = df.apply(lambda x: x==0, axis=0)
zero_counts = zero_cells.apply(lambda x: x.sum(), axis=1)
zero_counts[zero_counts == 1]


#0    False
#1     True
#2     True
#3    False
#dtype: bool
```